# Android: how to avoid Method invocation... may produce 'NullPointerException' warning?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I do the following:

```
if (!items.containsKey(item) || items.get(item).getPrice() != 0) continue;
```

For the above I get the warning. In order to avoid it, I do

```
Objects.requireNonNull(items.get(item)).getPrice() != 0
```

The above works but it's not clean and anyway, I just checked that the item exists so for sure it's not null.

Is there a cleaner way? Thanks

Here is the full line of code:

```
if (!Utils.getInstance().items.containsKey(item.getId()) || Objects.requireNonNull(Utils.getInstance().items.get(item.getId())).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could annotate your method/variable with @NonNull

```
@NonNull
    fun test(){

    }

@NonNull
private lateinit var test:List<String>
```

Comment: but it can be null if the item is not there.

Comment: @NonNull would ensure that a parameter, field or method return value can never be null for the fields we're sure it won't be null.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should change your if condition from

`if (!items.containsKey(item) || items.get(item).getPrice() != 0) continue;`

to

`if (items.get(item) == null || items.get(item).getPrice() != 0) continue;`

Comment: Perhaps it will work but it's not cleaner :) I was hoping that lint would know that I just made sure it's not null. I know that in certain cases, it does understand that by itself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ensure that `items` contains the key `item`, just do it in following way:

```java
Object value = items.get(item);
if (value == null || value.getPrice() != 0) continue;
```

Comment: I still get the warning. Not sure if related but I didn't separate it into 2 lines and I use a variable that resides in a singleton.

Comment: @Amos Please paste your warning

Comment: Method invocation 'getPrice' may produce 'NullPointerException'

Comment: I also updated the question with the full line I have

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Utils.getInstance().items.containsKey(item.getId()) || Objects.requireNonNull(Utils.getInstance().items.get(item.getId())).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

That's quite a feat for a code!

You make to many logic in a single line.You need to divide it to a more readable one.

---

Let's simplify your code,

First, remove the `requireNonNull`. So it will be like this:

```
 if (!Utils.getInstance().items.containsKey(item.getId()) || Utils.getInstance().items.get(item.getId()).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

Second, extract `Utils.getInstance().items` to a single variable. So, it will be like this (Here I **assume** you're using a `Map` with `HashMap`):

```
// assuming a HashMap
HashMap items = Utils.getInstance().items;

if (!items.containsKey(item.getId()) || items.get(item.getId()).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

Third, we extract the key as a single variable:

```
// assuming a HashMap
HashMap items = Utils.getInstance().items;

// assuming a string as the key
String key = item.getId();

if (!items.containsKey(key) || items.get(key).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

Now, we can split the `or` part to this:

```
// assuming a HashMap
HashMap items = Utils.getInstance().items;

// assuming a string as the key
String key = item.getId();

if (!items.containsKey(key)) continue;

if(items.get(key).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

the last code will gives you warning because `Map.get()` can return a `null` value. You can see from [Map.get()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map#get(java.lang.Object)) documentation. So, we need to guard it.

**Here the final version**:

```
// assuming a HashMap
HashMap items = Utils.getInstance().items;

// assuming a string as the key
String key = item.getId();

if (!items.containsKey(key)) continue;

if(items.get(key) == null) continue;

if(items.get(key).getPrice() == 0) continue;
```

It maybe end up with more extra lines for your code. But it makes your code more readable and maintainable because you don't need to push your brain to hard to understand the code.